# How many ways to arrange 10 values in a vector of length 50?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial

I have a set of values $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ that I want to place in vectors of length 50 in all permutations.

So far I'm using the permutation formula with $n=50$, $r=10$ as
$$
\frac{50!}{(50-10)!} = 3.73*10^{16}
$$
Is this correct? It seems inconceivably large... If this is correct, can someone elucidate how I can go about conceptualizing this? I've started with

`50 ways to have all 1's and a 2.
50 ways to have all 1's and a 3.
...
50 ways to have all 1's and a 10.
= 9*50 = 450.`

then

`50 ways to have all 2's and a 1.
50 ways to have all 2's and a 3.
...
50 ways to have all 2's and a 10.
= 9*50 = 450`

...

`=450*9 = 4,050.`

Comment: If the values can be arbitrarily selected in each of the 50 positions then they are not called permutations and the permutation formula does not apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector you want to build up can be seen as a number of $50$ digit in base $10$ ($=$ length of the alphabet).

The answer is $10^{50}$.

This is called "sequence with repetition", no permutation.

Similarly, it can be seen as the number of words of $50$ letters given an alphabet of $10$ letters.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $10^{49}$? Because for a 3-digit number with base-10 system, $10^2$ fills 3 spaces, e.g. 100.

Comment: Oh but $10^3$ is like 999. I see now. So it should be $10^{50} - 1$, right?

Comment: Ah no but 000 counts in this case so it's $10^3$. Got it, many thanks for your insight.